# Using SO/SX in classroom; following users; detecting user-network up-voting abuse

Tags: discussion, upvotes, users

I am a university instructor, and I am considering requiring my students to use SO/SX as a way to engage the subject matter. The idea is that part of their grade would be a direct reflection of their SO/SX account points earned in the relevant subdomain during the semester.

There are some problems that I can foresee:

- Posting half-baked/lame questions just to get points
- Back-scratching deals where students up-vote one another for grades instead of for content.

I see the SX communities as a great place to learn - and learn *how* to learn - so I want my students to experience it. At the same time, I do not want to violate the purpose of the communities. My questions are:

- Can I "follow" users, the same way that you follow someone on Twitter or Facebook?
- Is it possible to automatically detect systematic user-network up-voting?
- Is this whole concept a bad idea?

Comment: Grading students based on their Stack Overflow reputation sounds like a **Bad Idea** on so many levels...for one, there's the motivation to cheat the system, and then another issue is that your re-enforcing the misconception that reputation is an accurate measure of skill in a subject matter, when it's really just a measure of how much the system (and the community as a whole) trusts you with site privileges, and even *then* the system is often cheated, as in the case of high-rep plagiarists...

Comment: So the consensus seems to be that this is a bad idea, especially with the assumption that a grade should reflect expertise/mastery. If part of a grade were given for showing effort to become proficient with a tool of the trade, then it would make more sense, except that earning rep points is a fairly random/unreliable process, as TZHX and Magisch have pointed out.

Comment: Huh, funny how people downvote because they think it is a bad idea, even though the question is well-formulated and clear (if I do say so myself)

Answer (score 14):

> - Can I "follow" users, the same way that you follow someone on Twitter or Facebook?

No. Each user has an RSS feed you could subscribe to. Look for "User Feed" on the summary page of their profile ([here's mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/519348), for example). This likely won't contain all the information you want.

> - Is it possible to automatically detect systematic user-network up-voting?

The system already attempts to do this. It's fuzzy though, so you couldn't rely on it catching all instances, and you wouldn't have access to the information to perform your own analysis.

> - Is this whole concept a bad idea?

Yes. Basing a student's grade on something which pretty much amounts to luck and timing is a bad idea. In the ideal of Stack Overflow, a question should only be asked once. Assuming that the subject you are teaching is brand new, your quickest student to post might be able to post an on-topic question, the others should get closed.

Some people ask questions for the most trivial problems they encounter -- assuming their questions aren't terrible, they might build up a few points doing this. Some people want to go an learn it themselves and will instead focus on official documentation, experimenting, etc. The second group will have a better knowledge of what's going on, and be more equipped for the future, but will be penalised by your grading.

Answer (score 9):

> Is this whole concept a bad idea?

**Yes, please don't do this.**

There are several reasons why that is an exceedingly poor idea:

- SO Reputation does not in any way indicate expertise in the subject. It is a tool denoting the amount of trust the community places in you to complete  moderation tasks, nothing more.
- Reputation gains are largely dictated by random chance. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163772/what-is-the-difference-between-casting-to-float-and-adding-f-as-a-suffix-whe/33163841#33163841) for an example, thats a post i've made that contains only very basic concepts of C - 50 upvotes. Just because mine happened to be the one of the 10 good answers that the asker selected, at random.
- Points are largely earned by activity, and can be earned at by not participating in expert discussions of the subject matter, but by simple moderation tasks. Up to 1000 rep can be earned by making edits that get accepted, even if they just fix grammar. This would turn your student's grade in forced community service correcting grammar, at least partially.
- You encourage your students to actively fish for upvotes, which is detrimental to site quality.

> Is it possible to automatically detect systematic user-network
>   up-voting?

SO has Algorhitms that detect serial voting patterns and delete those.

> Can I "follow" users, the same way that you follow someone on Twitter
>   or Facebook?

Besides visiting their profile manually, not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

My advice, for what it's worth, is to have them read a programming related blog, like

- Eric Lippert's [Fabulous Adventures In Coding](http://ericlippert.com/)
- Raymond Chen's [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/)
- the (almost) always enjoyable [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) by Alex Papadimoulis (and company)
- Jon Skeet's [Coding Blog](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/) (Hasn't been updated in a while)

Reading programming related blogs is a habit that will serve them far better in the long run then some imaginary [unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/305827) points.

SO is a great place for a self-motivated person to find the answers to their questions, but it's really not a place to come learn from first principles. We can answer focused, practical questions about the software process, but general, open ended discussions don't help anyone here. We aren't set up for the iterative nature of learning a skill.

Asking poorly thought out, fluff questions in an eleventh-hour drive to stat pad, actively hurts the community, and makes more cleanup work. Right now there are 9000+ questions in the close vote review queue.  (Its only gotten that low because of the herculean efforts of many members.) That's 9000+ questions that have to be reviewed, classified, and fixed. While one class won't generate that much additional noise, there are plenty of lecturers who will have the same idea, and even 20 classes worth of students flooding the site with junk questions would be difficult to keep up with.

Lastly, reputation != expertise.  Reputation means that you've contributed in a way that the community as a whole finds useful. Since useful contributions are what we need, privileges come with it. That's why a new user can gain +2 each time they edit a post. (Raymond Chen, *the* expert on the Windows API and it's history has 32k.)

Comment: +1 for plagiarizing my favorite blogs list ...

Comment: -1 and flagged for plagiarism. Kidding...

Comment: Thanks @Bob  I saw the word 'plagiarism' in my notifications and I knew right away who it had to be. :)